# calculate CDF from given PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to understand the calculate the CDF from the given PDF

> $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0.5& 0\le x<1\\ 1& 1\le x<1.5\\ 0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

The CDF is

> $F(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x<0\\ 0.5x & 0\le x<1\\ x-0.5 & 1\le x<1.5\\ 1 & x\ge 1.5\end{cases}$

Can anyone please describe how

> $0.5x$ for $0\le x<1$

and

> $x-0.5$ for $1\le x<1.5$

are calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the pdf $f(x)$ then the cdf is obtained via integration

$$
F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x {f(t)}~{\rm d}t \tag{1}
$$

For your case

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1/2 &  0 \leq x <1\\
1 & 1 \leq x < 3/2\\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases} \tag{2}
$$

It is just a matter on calculating the integral

> $x < 0$

If $x < 0$ then, $f(x) = 0$ and

$$
F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)~{\rm d}t = 0 \tag{3}
$$

> $ 0 \leq x < 1$ in this range the $f(x) = 1/2$ so that

$$
F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)~{\rm d}t = \int_{-\infty}^{0}f(t)~{\rm d}t + \int_{0}^{x}f(t)~{\rm d}t = 0 + \int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{2}~{\rm d}t  = \frac{x}{2}\tag{4}
$$

> $1 \leq x < 3/2 $

As before

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)~{\rm d}t &=& \int_{-\infty}^{0}f(t)~{\rm d}t + \int_{0}^{1}f(t)~{\rm d}t + \int_{1}^{x}f(t)~{\rm d}t \\
&=& 0 + \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2}~{\rm d}t + \int_{1}^{x}1~{\rm d}t \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} + (x - 1) = x - \frac{1}{2} \tag{5}
\end{eqnarray}

> $x > 3/2$

Finally

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)~{\rm d}t &=& \int_{-\infty}^{0}f(t)~{\rm d}t + \int_{0}^{1}f(t)~{\rm d}t + \int_{1}^{3/2}f(t)~{\rm d}t + \int_{3/2}^{x}f(t)~{\rm d}t\\
&=& 0 + \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2}~{\rm d}t + \int_{1}^{3/2}1~{\rm d}t + 0\\
&=& \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1 \tag{6}
\end{eqnarray}

> 

If you put everything together you'd get

$$
F(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\
x/2 & 0 \leq x < 1 \\
x - 1/2 & 1 \leq x < 3/2 \\
1 & x > 3/2
\end{cases}
$$